# Path finding well know problems

Tags: heuristics

Is there any pathfinding trivial problems like the TSP?

I know that is possible to solve TSP using A*, Best-first and using spanning tree and other things as heuristic but, is there any problem well know by the AI community?

Comment: I don't understand your question. TSP is **NP**-complete: that's pretty much the opposite of being trivial.

Comment: well, my point was. TSP is a popular problem, i would like to know another pathfinding problem that is as popular as tsp.

Comment: Maybe look into some generalizations of TSP (you'll find examples from Wikipedia).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A different kind of pathfinding problem could be the solving of a [sliding puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sliding_puzzle). Which can be implemented using a*. You can pass in a board configuration like:

```
ed_o
nmac
jibf
hglk
```

and find a path to an inputted solution:

```
abcd
efgh
ijkl
mno_
```

An admissible heuristic for this could be [city-block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry) distance.